# Is there a cheap way to recover refrigerant from an AC system

Tags: ac, refrigerant, recovery

I have a car with a leaky AC and had to refill it with refrigerant in order to identify the source of the leak. My luck, the evaporator core seems to be the problem and I have to drain the system before I can do the repair.

I did look into a few recovery machine sur as this [one](https://de-jbtools.glopalstore.com/mastercool-69110-portable-a-c-recovery-unit/?gclid=Cj0KCQjwudb3BRC9ARIsAEa-vUsDa3dSKtyR35p9hiUfWKjWB5YxyQnrH14XOsr3oPBSkxidBxGYLdMaAm2vEALw_wcB), but they are not cheap and for something I am likely to use twice in a lifetime, I was wondering if there were cheaper alternatives to it (appart from asking a mechanics to do it for me, which I am also considering :-)

So far, I have a vacuum pump, which I thought could somehow be used to recover the refrigerant.
Could I maybe hook it up to a Vacuum chamber, with a filter in between so that the refrigerant is decontaminated and can then be reinjected into the system once fixed?
Not sure these Vacuum chambers are made for such things though.

Comment: Get it done with the proper equipment. You have been given this advice in the comments to this answer: https://mechanics.stackexchange.com/a/76817/10976

Comment: That is not the same question!

Comment: I did **not** say it is the same question, but the advice given is relevant and imho correct. You should perhaps re-read it.

Comment: I would not advise any "Rube Goldberg or Heath Robinson" method to try to evacuate the refrigerant from the system. The safety issues and consequences can be fatal. a good entry ticket for a Darwin Award. Mind you if the leak is significant then soon they will not be any refrigerant left to remove.

Comment: Thanks @SolarMike, so it sounds like I have only 2 options. Either ask a professional to drain the system for me or spend the money on equipement :-)

Comment: I have all the knowledge and skills to design, test, build and commission refrigerant systems as I taught both the theory and practical in a university for an engineering degree. I take my car to two garages (in two different countries) as they have the equipment which is worth about 5k and do the job in quick time. Much as I would like to play again with the systems and parameters (H2, H2S etc) it is not worth it.

Comment: Thanks @SolarMike, are you saying I should not even replace the Evaporator Core on my own? Or only recommending to get the AC emptied, checked and refilled by a pro?

Comment: Once the system is safely emptied, you can. Make absolutely certain that you don't introduce **any** dirt or contaminants into the system while doing so. Then get them to test and refill.

Comment: No need. What I said is clear.

Comment: Are you sure it even has any refrigerant in the system at this point?  With a leak it's quite possible it's empty at this point.  You'll probably also want to replace the dryer unit as that will become contaminated with a long-term opened system like you have.

Comment: Depends on how handy your are, I have built several low cost recovery machines, but may not be legal in some area's.

Comment: @Moab, I am pretty handy, but lacking time :-)

Comment: The question is about a *cheap* way to recover the refrigerant. Professionals with professional certification and professional equipment are an option; however, they are not cheap. This question has an answer with a cheap method: https://mechanics.stackexchange.com/questions/9865/can-you-use-a-vacuum-pump-on-a-charged-a-c-system/46355#46355 (I may not agree that the method is easy. The question, again, was about a cheap method.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In answer to your question, NO, you cannot use a standard vacuum pump to recover the refrigerant from an A/C system. They are not designed for this purpose and will not do what you need it to do.

A HVAC recovery system is design to pull the existing refrigerant out of your vehicle and them pump it into a receiving tank.  It's essentially two pumps in one.  A standard vacuum pump will not pump the extracted refrigerant into a tank.

Is there a "cheap" way of doing this?  Sure, open the system and vent it into the air.  But this is dangerous and in most places illegal.  So no, this is NOT a good idea!  DON'T DO IT!  Not only that but you waste a significant amount of refrigerant that is fairly expensive.

If you lack the know-how (and that seems to be the case) and the equipment (which is clearly the case) then you should employ an licensed automotive HVAC technician to evacuate your system.  After your repairs are completed take it back and have them refill the system.

That approach may cost you some money but it's likely to be much less expensive than purchasing the right equipment.

Comment: Thank you for very much for your answer. I will ask a mechanic to empty the system and do the work myself. I wish I could upvote your answer, sorry about that.